# Liquibase Error Generating/Inserting varbinary(max) data from SQL Server

Tags: liquibase

I'm generating a changelog from a SQL Server database which I would like to use to create an Oracle version. One of the tables has a varbinary(max) column and contains data to bring over as well. The generated inserts from this table look like this:

```
<changeSet author=... id="1415603816743-555">
    <insert tableName="my_table">
        <column name="my_table_id" value="0007JL11X000OZ10J60000948UM000000P8P"/>
        ...
        <column name="my_table_image" value="[B@70eded35"/>
        ...
    </insert>
    ...
</changeSet>
```

This throws an "ORA-01465: invalid hex number" when I attempt to insert the my_table_image data on the Oracle side (target column is a BLOB).
The original data on the SQL Server side is hex. Any ideas on how to successfully generate/update from the changelog to both SQL Server varbinary(max) and Oracle BLOB? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Liquibase is probably not the right tool to use for this kind of data transfer. Liquibase is primarily concerned with database *structure* rather than database *contents*. For transferring simple data (strings, numerics, etc.) Liquibase can do the job, but for something like pictures I would look at more specialized ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) tools.

The tool I have used most and had success with (although I've never done image data, so YMMV) is called Pentaho - they have a free open-source "community" version that might work for you.

Comment: Yes, Liquibase has some support for reading in values to blob/clob fields with valueBlobFile and valueClobFile instead of just "value", but generateChangeLog does not currently support generating them.